# Session destroys after clicking Empty Basket

Tags: php

So I am developing a website like ebay where customer can purchase product, add to basket etc. The problem is that every time I click "Empty Basket", the session stops/destroys (I use session_destroy to empty the cart) and I have to **re-login** my account. Is there a way where user stays logged in every time s/he clicks empty basket?

```
if(isset($_GET["emptybasket"]) && $_GET["emptybasket"]==1)
{
    $return_url = base64_decode($_GET["return_url"]); //return url
    session_destroy();
    header('Location:'.$return_url);
}
```

I tried deleting `session_destroy()` but the basket still has products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the items the user has added to their basket in an array, then just unset it when they want to clear their basket.

```
$_SESSION['basket'] // Store basket in here

unset($_SESSION['basket']); // Clear the basket
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of destroying your session you should just unset the cart variable of your session.

```
unset($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Or

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = '';
```